# How to check for XmlDeclaration in XmlDocument C#

Tags: c#, xml

What is the more efficient way to check an XmlDocument for an XmlDeclaration node?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What sort of "efficiency" are you after? Efficiency of expression, or efficiency at execution time? Here's a LINQ query which finds the declaration pretty quickly:

```
XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.ChildNodes
                                .OfType<XmlDeclaration>()
                                .FirstOrDefault();
```

I strongly suspect that will be efficient enough. It's possible that you could *just* test whether the first child node was an `XmlDeclaration`... I don't *think* anything else can come before it.

If there's any possibility of using LINQ to XML instead, then it becomes even easier - you just use the [`XDocument.Declaration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.declaration.aspx) property.

Comment: you're remembering right, the declaration can't have anything - including whitespace - before it, allowing for greater efficiency in both expression and execution.

Answer (score 12):

To check it has one:

```
bool hasDec = doc.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration;
```

To obtain it if it has one:

```
XmlDeclaration dec = doc.FirstChild as XmlDeclaration;
```

Remember that there is no content allowed prior to the XML declaration (barring a BOM, which isn't considered content, but an encoding artefact in the stream, so won't have a corresponding node).